# Bash auto-completion slow: /bin/bash hangs at rl_getc

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When pressing `tab` to autocomplete a command (e.g. `cd`) bash hangs for a couple of seconds before completing it.

- when using `set -x` nothing is printed prior to the hang
- When using a  tty console from `Ctrl-Alt-FXX` there is no lag
- strace reveals that the problem is in `rl_getc`:

```
3428  11:03:21.516869 pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = 1 (in [0]) <3.154249>
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so(pselect+0x59) [0x116dc9]
 > /bin/bash(rl_getc+0xb2) [0xc4032]
 > /bin/bash(rl_read_key+0xc4) [0xc48c4]
 > /bin/bash(readline_internal_char+0x77) [0xad187]
 > /bin/bash(readline+0x45) [0xad945]
 > /bin/bash(reader_loop+0x699) [0x32759]
 > /bin/bash(decode_prompt_string+0x101d) [0x34b3d]
 > /bin/bash(read_secondary_line+0x2aca) [0x37b8a]
 > /bin/bash(yyparse+0x428) [0x3b308]
 > /bin/bash(parse_command+0x36) [0x31ef6]
 > /bin/bash(read_command+0x58) [0x31ff8]
 > /bin/bash(reader_loop+0x119) [0x321d9]
 > /bin/bash(main+0xecf) [0x30c8f]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x21c87]
 > /bin/bash(_start+0x2a) [0x3155a]
```

(logged with `sudo strace -t -k -t -f -T -s9999 -p3428`)

I have  tried the steps [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70885/how-to-debug-and-fix-slow-autocomplete-in-bash?newreg=0103768ec65a42ce8668f359a569642b) including uninstalling git and turning my sound off.
I have also commented out the contents of my `.bashrc` to no avail.

Any ideas on what could be the issue here?

Comment: What is your terminal type? If you run `TERM=dumb` does it help? It **might** be that your terminal definition has function key sequences that start with tab, so bash is waiting to see if there are any more characters to be sent. Does pressing `tab` `tab` help at all? Do you have a `~/.inputrc`? What is the output of `bind -p | grep C-i`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug and fix slow autocomplete in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70885/how-to-debug-and-fix-slow-autocomplete-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on macOS with iTerm2.
I resolved the issue by checking the "Silence bell" option in iTerm.

*Settings* > *Profiles(Default)* > *Terminal* > *Notifications* > ✅ *Silence bell*

See: [How to debug and fix slow autocomplete in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70885/how-to-debug-and-fix-slow-autocomplete-in-bash/617556#617556?newreg=077af70237ac47909a8c77dac4f154ad)